# Round the number of decimals

Tags: sql, decimal, rounding

I need to round the number of decimals from 3 to 2 in the column `brutto`.
The correct should be `12633.750000`.

Is there a easy way to do this?

[image]

Comment: Which DB flavour? What datatype is that column? Do you want rounding on select or on insert? Can you change the table definition?

Answer (score 0):

Some dbms products have `round`:

```
round(brutto,2)
```

ANSI SQL way would be a double `cast`:

```
cast((cast(brutto as decimal (12,2)) as decimal(15,5))
```

Answer (score 0):

In Any database, you can do this by converting to a `decimal` with two decimal places.  For instance:

```
select cast(brutto as decimal(10, 2))
```

Many databases will also let you alter the type of the column.  Something like:

```
alter table brutto alter brutto decimal(10, 2);
```

However, not all databases support this (or a similar) syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:

UPDATE acc_data
SET brutto = ROUND (brutto, 2)
where doc_id = '00C19695AB574568B9590508A4601E9F'